# Retrieving value from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, c#

I have three tables

- `tab_contactlist` (contact_id(identity(1,1) not null), name, address, phoneno, emailaddress)
- `tab_group` (group_id (identity(1,1) not null), group_name)
- `tab_information` (contact_id, group_id)

My question is while inserting the value into `tab_contactlist` and `tab_group` then how to store two tables (`tab_contactlist, tab_group`) id into `tab_contactlist` where `contact_id` and `group_id` is in `tab_contactlist` ..

Can anyone have any idea about this? Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #tab_contactlist(
contact_id int identity(1,1) not null
,name varchar (100)
,address varchar (100)
,phoneno varchar (100)
,emailaddress varchar (100)
)

create table #tab_group(
group_id int identity(1,1) not null
,group_name varchar (100)
)

create table #tab_information(
contact_id int 
,group_id int 
)

declare @contact_id_var int 
declare @group_id_var int

insert into #tab_contactlist (name,address,phoneno,emailaddress) 
    values ('name1','address1','phoneno1','emailaddress1') 
select @contact_id_var = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into #tab_group (group_name) values ('group_name1') 
select @group_id_var = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into #tab_information(contact_id,group_id) values (@contact_id_var ,@group_id_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @contact_id_var int
declare @group_id_var int

insert into tab_contactlist (....) values (....)
select @contact_id_var = @@IDENTITY

insert into tab_groupvalues (....) values (....)
select @group_id_var = @@IDENTITY

insert into tab_information(contact_id,group_id) values (@contact_id_var ,@group_id_var)
```

Comment: also can put all in transaction to be sure that all inserts succeed

Comment: sir... i already inserted the value into the tab_contactlist and tab_groupvalues i want to extract contact_id and group_id into tab_information

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx check this

select @contact_id_var = @@IDENTITY !!!!

Comment: after insert into tab_contactlist  and insert into tab_groupvalues you need to select the identity of the last insertted row. you have identity property on so you can use 
@@IDENTITY  function for geting this values into variables and then to insert them into 3rd table.

Comment: i am in confusion sir i use scope identity for retrieving value but dont know how to operate